# Looping 2 Lists based on greater size

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

Are there any way to loop 2 lists based on greater size ? Reason being some records in either lists might not be exists in the other list, but i still need to insert it into a table

For example Lists A size is 6, Lists B size is 10, or vice versa

my method is this, but i think is not efficient enough

```
if(listsA.size() > listsB.size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < listsA.size(); i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; i < listsB.size(); j ++) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}else if(listsA.size() < listsB.size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < listsB.size(); i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; i < listsA.size(); j ++) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

EDITED : use cases would be like comparing 2 files from 2 different folder and generate a report summary. if a file is in folder A, but not in folder B, will still generate report.

```
for(File brmFile:brmDirectory.listFiles()) {
    for(File bscsFile:bscsDirectory.listFiles()) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

or comparing 2 sets of data.  if a data is not found in 1 of the list, will still process the 2 lists.

[UPDATED] : lists example

List A : [Type : Type A, Amount : 5], [Type : Type B, Amount : 10]

List B : [Type : Type A, Amount : 5], [Type : Type B, Amount : 10], [Type :  Type C, Amount : 7]

if my understanding of nested loop is correct, if i do the below code

```
for(int i = 0; i < listsA.size(); i ++) {
    for(int j = 0; i < listsB.size(); j ++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

3rd Element of List B will be skipped right ? since List A will loop twice only, and loop List B 3 times to search for List A elements

Comment: You are missing the case of equal list sizes. You can change one if() condition to >= and drop the other if() condition (keeping the else). Aside from that, an actual use case would be helpful.

Comment: Without other information, this looks warbled together. When the lists would be sorted, when you do some kind of merging. When the lists actually could have been Sets.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen added some description of use cases. hope its clear

Comment: You have nested loops, if one list has 4 entries and the other one has 3, the "do something" part will run 4*3 times. Similarly in the file-listing example: you will go through the entire list of `bscsDirectory` for every element of `brmDirectory`. So far it doesn't matter which one is the shorter or longer, 3*4 and 4*3 are both 12. Of course there's a chance that you don't want that 12, but it's unclear what you want to achieve here.

Comment: "if a data is not found in 1 of the list, will still process the 2 lists." - sound like both lists could be processed independently. Nesting the loops of list A and list B only makes sense, if the consequenting action depends on A *and* B.

Comment: @tevemadar I have updated the thread. not sure if im understanding nested loop correctly.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen yes. my question is either List A or List B will have greater size, but i need to loop them together to check if the records exists in either List or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is alright, but you could always use a `switch` statement instead of an `if` statement like so:

```
switch(listsA.size() > listsB.size){
  //case1 true:
    //do something
  ...   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself), you can try this version, where first you find what bigger and smaller values, and loop using those values

```
int biggerSize = Math.max(a.size(), b.size());
int smallerSize = Math.min(a.size(), b.size());

for (int i = 0; i < biggerSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < smallerSize; j++) {
        // do something
    }
}
```